# Using Antlr with JavaScript target with React

Tags: javascript, antlr4

I am trying to follow the standard practice using antlr in my client side js application created using default react configuration.

However, the generated file has the following error:

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Class constructor Lexer cannot be invoked without 'new'


  47 | function MyGrammarLexer(input) {
> 48 |  antlr4.Lexer.call(this, input);
  49 |     this._interp = new antlr4.atn.LexerATNSimulator(this, atn, decisionsToDFA, new antlr4.PredictionContextCache());
  50 |     return this;
  51 | }
```

It seems that the generated code violates JS requirement by calling a class (antlr.Lexer) using call. How to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure antlr version for codegen matches js runtime library antlr version